# How to go back to the previous mode in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to save the mode as a variable in vim? For example, I am trying to do something like this as a mapping:

- `[esc]` `0` // go to the start of the line

Except, I want to 'keep' the mode that I was in before -- for example, if I was previously in `insert` mode, I would like the command to do:

- `[esc]` `0` `i`

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have an example on how this would work? What mode are you in when your previous mode is insert mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at this in a different way. Instead of describing what you want to do (finding a way to go back two or three modes, which I think might not be possible), you should describe what you wish to achieve (for example, "go to the beginning of the line while in insert mode").

If you want to go to the beginning of the line while in insert mode, you could create a mapping like this:

```vim
inoremap <F2> <C-O>0
```

When you press <kbd>F2</kbd>, this mapping will use the special key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> to enter normal mode and execute one command (the `0` command to go to the beginning of the line) before returning to insert mode. You can map the command to most keys, but you should choose something you rarely want to press while in insert mode, e.g. two uppercase characters or symbols that are not often used together.

There are more examples and information in the article [Quick command in insert mode](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Quick_command_in_insert_mode)  from the Vim Tips Wiki.

Comment: thanks, what's the difference between pressing `<kbd>esc</kbd>` and `ctrl`-`0` ? (also, is it possible to get the keys in a comment?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the difference is how the cursor moves. If your cursor is here in insert mode: `a|bc, then pressing `Esc` will select the `a` while `Ctrl-O` will select the `b`. Also, `Ctrl-O` automatically reenters insert mode, while with `Esc` you will have to do so yourself. (And no, the <kbd> code is not supported in comments.)